# Get Text From All Columns in a Table Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns and 5 rows. I want to get all the text on the 3rd column of my table and put it on a label for some purposes. I'm only able to do it per row. I want it to be all the rows in the 3rd column. Is it possible?

Here's my code:

```
String a = (String) tb_records.getModel().getValueAt(1, 2);
lb_get.setText(a);
```

tb_records is the variable name of my table and
lb_get is the variable name of my label where I want to put all the text

Answer (score 0):

[JTable API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

```
String a;

for(int i = 0; i < tb_records.getRowCount; i++){

    a = (String) tb_records.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3);
    lb_get.setText(lb_get + a);

}
```